# How to set default-selected range for <calendar-range> component with Vue2-datepicker?

Tags: javascript, vue2-datepicker, calendar-range

I need to set the default (selected) date range for  component, so that when user returns to previously-completed date selection, the selection isn't lost (which currently happens because component is re-rendered)

[image: Set default date selection]

I've checked the code in https://github.com/mengxiong10/vue2-datepicker/blob/master/src/calendar/calendar-range.js but can't seem to see a prop for this.

I have tried setting the defaultValue prop as an array: (but it doesn't work)

```
<calendar-range
                                @select="updateSelectedDateRange"
                                :defaultValue="dateRange"
                                :value="dateRange"
                            ></calendar-range>
```

Inspecting with vue inspect tool

[image]